# Integral of $e^{\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: integration

I want to calculate $$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \exp{\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\right)}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$ 
Moreover, I want to generalize it to more than $2$ dimensions, i.e., $$\int\cdots\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \exp{\left(\frac{1}{1+\sum_{i=1}^dx_i^2}\right)}\,\mathrm dx_1\cdots \,\mathrm dx_{d}.$$ 
If it helps, you can use the limits on $x_i$'s to be $0$ and $1$.
What I could do is to say that for small $\exp{\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\right)}$ is close to $\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}$, but even then, except for $\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx$ whose integral is $\tan^{-1}(x)$, I don't know the form for others.

Comment: You should probably switch to polar coordinates

Comment: In the general form, is it $1+\sum$ or $1/(1+\sum)$?

Comment: Sorry. Corrected.

Comment: This obviously diverges in $\mathbb R^d$ as the integrand tends to $1$ all around.

Answer (score 1):

About the first part:
$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\right)\,dx\,dy =2\pi \int_{0}^{+\infty}\rho\exp\left(\frac{1}{1+\rho^2}\right)\,d\rho =\pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(\frac{1}{1+z}\right)\,dz$$
equals
$$ \pi\int_{1}^{+\infty}\exp\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\,dt = \pi\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^u}{u^2}\,du $$
which is divergent since $e^u\geq 1+u$. If the integration range is $[0,1]^2$ we have
$$ \iint_{[0,1]^2}\exp\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\right)\,dx\,dy =\\ \underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\pi\rho}{2}\exp\left(\frac{1}{1+\rho^2}\right)\,d\rho}_{I_1} + \underbrace{\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\arccos\frac{1}{\rho}\right)\rho\exp\left(\frac{1}{1+\rho^2}\right)\,d\rho}_{I_2}$$
where
$$ I_1 = \frac{\pi}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\exp\left(\frac{1}{1+z}\right)\,dz = \frac{\pi}{4}\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{e^u}{u^2}\,du $$
depends on exponential integrals and $I_2$ can be dealt with in a similar fashion.

Comment: But the OP says $0\leq x_i\leq1$

Comment: @saulspatz: missed that, now adjusting.